# only one angular run block is executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my first run block in `user.route.js`

```
(function() {
'use strict';


angular
    .module('app.user' , [])
    .run(appRun);

function appRun(routerHelper) {
    console.log("-----------------------------------");
})();
```

and my second run block in user.cache.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.user' , [])
    .run(test);

function test(){
    console.log("test +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
})();
```

but only the first run code is executed. the display is:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're entirely redefining your `app.user` module there.
If you want to attach additional items to an existing module, leave out the second parameter to `.module()`:

```
angular.module('app.user').run(..)
```